# Try to return JSON data generated with SQL statement from PHP script to JS webpage but get null instead

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

I want to return **JSON** data from a resulted SQL statement in a PHP script upon pressing **Submit** button, but I receive `null` instead.

*I'll be using the returned JSON to filter-show markers on my Google Map, but for now I just want to get the data back across to my jQuery page from PHP script so I can manipulate/use it.*

**Submit button**:

*HTML*

```
<input type="submit" id="filter" value="Filter" />
```

*JS*

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var myData = $('#myform').serializeArray();
  $.getJSON('myscript.php', myData, function(json){
    alert(json);// actually filter for later                    
  });   
});
```

**PHP script**:

```
// action is a hidden form control I use to check if form was submitted
    if(isset($_POST["action"])){

        if(isset($_POST["color"]) && isset($_POST["zipcode"])){
            // try to open a connection to a MySQL server
            $connection = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect" . mysql_error());
            // select the active MySQL database to work with
            $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection) or die("Can\'t use db:" . mysql_error());

            $query = 'sql statement to return resutls based on what color and zipcode was provided';
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Can\'t do that: " . mysql_error());
        }

        //  close connection to the database


    echo json_encode($result);
    mysql_close($connection);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return the result object of a `mysql_query` call directly. You first have to parse it with functions like `mysql_fetch_array` or alike ([PHP docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)).

```
...
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ( $result === false ) {
  die("Can\'t do that: " . mysql_error());
}

$retVal = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
  $retVal[] = $row;
}

...
echo json_encode( $retVal );
```

**EDIT**

According to the jQuery spec for `getJSON` ([link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)), the data is sent using GET parameters and not using POST. So you would have to change all the `$_POST` appearances in your PHP code to either `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`.

Besides this, you should return some error messages if your variables are not set. Right now (according to your code) just an empty document is returned.

Comment: @Bob Did you use it with the `return` statement in the end or a `echo`? I had a short brainlag there.

Comment: @Bob Did you try calling the URL manually and check the results there?

Comment: I get this then - `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...`

Comment: @Bob Ok so try to remove the `or die(...)` part and move the check for errors to a separate statement like in my edited code.

Comment: I see the data now, but it doesn't get `alert()`ed in my JS page.

Comment: @Bob You tried changing the header information as suggested in the other answer?

Comment: I've read your edit. Thing is - I've hard coded my SQL statement ( no longer grabs values from `$_POST` or any other global variable ) to the data for now. Also, my client doesn't make any POST calls, even the form's method is set to `get` right now, yet I still get nothing.

Comment: @Bob If the code in this question is not the current one anymore, open a new question with the new code plz or edit the above question.

Comment: Now I get this in my client: `[object][Object],[object][Object],...`. For some reason my `echo` was inside the `while` loop.

Comment: @Bob seems like a valid response. If you want to watch it in more detail, you can serialize it again by using `alert( JSON.stringify( json ) );`.

Answer (score 1):

Before the echo you should declare the returned content type:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

If you want to check for the receival of the data you can use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
   data: myData,
   success: function(json) {},
   error: function(json) {} // this should allow you to check if data is received (but since the content type is set to text/html and $.getJSON expectr application/json it won't be a success)
});
```