# Can't get properties from JavaScript object created from JSON data generated by PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I have a PHP script that makes query to DB and returns the result as JSON data. This file contains some Codeigniter specific functions.

This functions recieve id and returns back to the JS code some data from a table.

```
public function get_l($id){
//$id is not empty variable
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$q=$this->db->get('news');

$res = $q->result_array();

$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$this->output->set_header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");

$out = json_encode($res);
$this->output->set_output($out);
}
```

And then I need to process that JSON with the next JS code:

```
function getContent(id){
  $.post('/admin_ajax/news/get',
  {
    id: id

  },
  function(result)
  {
    alert(result+"\n"+result.length);//this will output [object Object] 1
    for (var key in result)
    {
      alert(key+':'+result[key]); //and this 0:[object Object]
    }
    alert(result.title); //here we are getting undefined
  },
  'json'
);
```

I am not receiving errors or warnings in console. And in the firebug I see what was returned from the server.

HTTP headers:

```
Server  nginx/1.1.19
Date    Fri, 26 Oct 2012 11:59:12 GMT
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  85
Connection  keep-alive
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4
Cache-Control   post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
```

And response:

```
[{"id":"5","title":"test","alias":"test","content":"tes","date":"123","type":"test"}]
```

JSON:

```
alias  "test"

content "tes"

date  "123"

id "5"

title "test"

type "test"
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800811/try-to-return-json-data-generated-with-sql-statement-from-php-script-to-js-webpa) but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: A lot of code, but no question

Comment: Did you try with `echo $out;` instead `$this->output->set_output($out);`?

Comment: If you use `console.log()` and not `alert()`, you'll actually see the object? On the other hand, it looks like an array, and I'd try `result[0].title` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the response you are getting is actually an array with one element (the json object).

Try using `result[0]`, like so:

```
....
function(result)
  {
    alert(result[0]+"\n"+result[0].length);//this will output [object Object] 1
    for (var key in result[0])
    {
      alert(key+':'+result[0][key]); //and this 0:[object Object]
    }
    alert(result[0].title); //here we are getting undefined
  }
....
```

Comment: Yes, this is an array. And I can access to properties using first element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON object is in an array [...] hence the length 1.

```
function(result) {
    var jsonObj = result[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Result is an array with one element:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "test",
        "alias": "test",
        "content": "tes",
        "date": "123",
        "type": "test"
    }
]
```

The element at index 0 contains the information you need. You need to do:

```
alert(result[0].id);
alert(result[0].title);
alert(result[0].alias);
```